# Name Error: name 'enddata' is not defined (inside a function)

Tags: python

When I try to run this it says "enddata" is not defined, even though it is a list containing formatted data from the document. Is there a better way of coding this part?

```
def openfile ():

    global enddata
    global index

    file=open("weatherData.csv","r")
    data=file.readlines()
    file.close()

    enddata=[]
    index=0

    for sample in data:
        enddata.append(data[index].split(","))
        index +=1

    print("-"*50)

    return enddata

print(enddata)
```

Comment: Do you ever call the `openfile` function?

Comment: Friendly advice: try to forget that you ever knew about the existence of `global`. That would be the best advice anyone could offer here. Since `enddata` is the thing you want to make available 'outside' the `openfile` function you need only `return` it, which is what you have done. Since you `return enddata` you can make use of the result of the function by using `print(openfile())` rather than `print(enddata)`.

Comment: Don't use `global` - you did not define enddata globally and you did not call openfile() at all thats why you get the error.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As others pointed out, you have to call the `openfile` function: The code could be like this:

```
def openfile ():

    global enddata
    global index

    file=open("weatherData.csv","r")
    data=file.readlines()
    file.close()

    enddata=[]
    index=0

    for sample in data:
        enddata.append(data[index].split(","))
        index +=1

    print("-"*50)

    return enddata

openfile()
print(enddata)
```

Another way to do it a little more short and pythonic could be:

```
def openfile():
    with open("weatherData.csv") as f:
        return [line.split(',') for line in f]

enddata = openfile()
print("-"*50)
print(enddata)
```

Worth it to explore the [csv](https://docs.python.org/3/library/csv.html) Python module:

```
import csv

def openfile():
    with open('weatherData.csv') as f:
        return list(csv.reader(f))

enddata = openfile()
print("-"*50)
print(enddata)
```

Answer (score 0):

You have to call `openfile` for it to initialize (and create, for that matter) the global name `enddata`. However, you should not be using a global variable. Have `openfile` *return* the value you are assigning to `enddata` and assign it to the the variable in the calling scope.

A few other tips:

- Your function doesn't just open a file, it reads it and returns some data.
- Use a `with` statement to manage opening and closing the file.
- Don't read the entire file into memory at once; read it line by line.
- You are iterating over `data` twice, in some sense: once using the `for` loop, and again with `index`. It appears that `sample == data[index]` during each iteration. The entire iteration could be handled with a single list comprehension.
- Use the `csv` module for reading CSV files.

Putting it all together:

```
import csv

def read_file(fname):
    with open(fname) as fh:
        return list(csv.reader(fh))

enddata = read_file("weatherData.csv")
```

Answer (score 0):

This is a slightly more advanced way of writing your code.

- I use the `with statement so that I don't have to remember to close the file. It makes the code more compact in general.`weatherData` becomes the alias for the file.
- `sample` becomes the name for one line in the input file.
- It's important to note that each line in a file will have a so-called 'line-end' which has to be stripped off; hence the `.strip()`. Then I can do the `.split` on commas.
- Because each input line can contain more than one value, I use `.extend` to add them to `enddata`.
- I've written `print (openfile())` to see the results. Alternatively I could have written `result = openfile(); print(result)`.

.

```
def openfile():
    enddata = []
    with open('weatherData.csv') as weatherData:
        for sample in weatherData.readlines():
            enddata.extend(sample.strip().split(','))
    return enddata

print (openfile())
```

Output:

```
['1', '2', '3', '4', '5', '6']
```